# SQL Server multiple Exists where every exists has a NULL condition of main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, exists

I tried different ways and searched the web, but no luck so far.

I have query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   MainTable 
WHERE  exists (SELECT NULL FROM Table1.Column1 = MainTable.Column1 OR MainTable.Column1 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM Table2.Column2 = MainTable.Column2 OR MainTable.Column2 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM Table3.Column3 = MainTable.Column3 OR MainTable.Column3 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM Table4.Column4 = MainTable.Column4 OR MainTable.Column4 is NULL)
```

This works fine when Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4 are not empty. The real problem arises when any of the Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4 is empty and its corresponding ManinTable column is NULL, then that record gets ignored. The record is considered as does not exist because the `Is Null` condition will not execute. I cannot even take `Is Null` condition out of exists () as well because then query will return wrong result.

I want to get records from MainTable which exists in Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4 and also if corresponding column is null.

Edit: the following is the sample data and query which you can test and execute by yourself. To reproduce my problem just comment out the insertion query into Table4 and then execute, now it won't return any record because Table4 is empty hence Is Null for MainTable won't execute. So I will get no result.

```
CREATE Table #MainTable (Column1 INT NULL, Column2 INT NULL, Column3 INT NULL, Column4 INT NULL)
CREATE Table #Table1 (Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 INT)
CREATE Table #Table2 (Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 INT)
CREATE Table #Table3 (Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 INT)
CREATE Table #Table4 (Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 INT)

INSERT INTO #MainTable VALUES(1,2,3,NULL)
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES(1,2,3,4)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES(1,2,3,4)
INSERT INTO #Table3 VALUES(1,2,3,4)
INSERT INTO #Table4 VALUES(1,2,3,4)

SELECT *
FROM   #MainTable 
WHERE  exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table1 WHERE Column1 = #MainTable.Column1 OR #MainTable.Column1 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table2 WHERE Column2 = #MainTable.Column2 OR #MainTable.Column2 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table3 WHERE Column3 = #MainTable.Column3 OR #MainTable.Column3 is NULL) 
AND    exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table4 WHERE Column4 = #MainTable.Column4 OR #MainTable.Column4 is NULL)


Drop TABLE #MainTable
Drop TABLE #Table1
Drop TABLE #Table2
Drop TABLE #Table3
Drop TABLE #Table4
```

Comment: how about you posting some sample data and expected result ?

Comment: "This works fine when Table1, tabl2, Tabl3 and Table4 are not empty" - I have trouble believing that the code you posted works in any scenario. My guess is you need a "left outer join" instead of those "exists", but as GuidoG posted, sample data & expected results will help us help you :)

Comment: I am going to edit my answer and will add some sample data so that you can execute it by yourself and test it, in a moment. Though I cannot use joins because this is the part of a larger system and cannot simple replace exists with joins

Comment: Please check my answer I edited and added sample data and query to reproduce the problem

Comment: okay, thanks for your guidance halfter. Actually I am quite newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct what you want, than you have to change your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #MainTable 
WHERE  (Column1 is null or exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table1 WHERE Column1 = #MainTable.Column1)) 
AND    (Column2 is null or exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table2 WHERE Column2 = #MainTable.Column2)) 
AND    (Column3 is null or exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table3 WHERE Column3 = #MainTable.Column3)) 
AND    (Column4 is null or exists (SELECT NULL FROM #Table4 WHERE Column4 = #MainTable.Column4))
```

The problem with the original query is that is when the maintable.Column4 is null it was doing

```
WHERE Column4 = #MainTable.Column4
```

which is translated to

```
WHERE Column4 = NULL
```

and you cannot do = on a null value